# Any reason for pci-stub not working but vfio-pci working with QEMU/KVM GPU passthrough?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, virtual-machine, gpu

I am trying to passthrough a GPU device to a guest VM with QEMU/KVM and libvirt.

I successfully passed GPU to a guest VM when I was using vfio-pci to grab the GPU driver.

However, when I used pci-stub instead of vfio-pci to do the exact job, the virtual machine does not run and says:

Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devices.

Both pci-stub and vfio-pci modules were correctly enabled in the kernel configs but only vfio-pci worked.

Is there any reason that can make difference in pci-stub and vfio-pci?

Comment: I suspect that a libvirt sanity check is preventing it from unbinding from `pci-stub` to bind to `vfio-pci` automatically in ["managed" mode](https://libvirt.org/guide/html/Application_Development_Guide-Device_Config-PCI_Pass.html).  If `vfio-pci` is working for you now, why do you want to go to `pci-stub` instead?  In the case of myself and one other person, we found that [we had to boot with the device attached to `pci-stub` and then switch it to `vfio-pci` after boot](https://superuser.com/a/1045799/83694).

Comment: I just wanted to know why pci-stub is not working. When I tested pci-stub, I disabled vfio-pci from kernel config that libvirt does not try to bind to vfio-pci.

Comment: Maybe pci-stub is not supported anymore due to security issue?