# QEMU Radeon GPU passthrough with error code 43 after install driver

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, gpu, qemu

I'm trying to do a single [GPU passthrough](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF) and I actually got some results, it worked before having its driver installed, but after that it only shows the boot loading and then it turns into a black screen. Using VNC I managed to get this image:

[image]

I'm running it with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -name 'Win10' \
    -machine type=q35,accel=kvm,kernel_irqchip=on,vmport=off \
    -m 32G \
    -mem-path /run/hugepages/kvm \
    -cpu host,kvm=off,+kvm_pv_unhalt,+kvm_pv_eoi,topoext,amd-stibp=off,hv_relaxed,hv-vapic,hv-spinlocks=8191,hv_vpindex,hv-runtime,hv_time,hv-synic,hv-stimer,hv-vendor-id=123456789ab,hv-reset,hv-frequencies \
    -smp 16,sockets=1,cores=8,threads=2 \
    -nodefaults \
    -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd \
    -smbios 'type=1,uuid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' \
    -netdev user,id=n0,hostfwd=tcp::5900-:5900 \
    -device e1000,netdev=n0 \
    -object input-linux,id=kbd0,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-SONiX_USB_DEVICE-event-kbd,grab_all=on,repeat=on \
    -object input-linux,id=mouse0,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Razer_Razer_DeathAdder_Essential-event-mouse \
    -device virtio-mouse-pci \
    -device virtio-keyboard-pci \
    -monitor telnet::5555,server,nowait \
    -nographic \
    -vga none \
    -display none \
    -device vfio-pci,host=2d:00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on,x-pci-sub-vendor-id=0x1458,x-pci-sub-device-id=0x232c \
    -device vfio-pci,host=2d:00.1 \
    -rtc base=localtime,clock=host,driftfix=slew \
    -object iothread,id=io0 \
    -drive 'if=none,id=disk0,format=qcow2,aio=threads,cache=writeback,l2-cache-size=64M,cache-clean-interval=900,file=win.qcow2' \
    -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=disk0,iothread=io0 \
    -drive "media=cdrom,file=$HOME/virtio.iso" \
    -boot c
```

- `kernel_irqchip=on` was suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#QEMU_4.0:_Unable_to_load_graphics_drivers/BSOD/Graphics_stutter_after_driver_install_using_Q35) and [here](https://mathiashueber.com/fighting-error-43-nvidia-gpu-virtual-machine/)
- `vmport=off` was suggested [here](https://mathiashueber.com/fighting-error-43-nvidia-gpu-virtual-machine/)
- `kvm=off` and `hv-vendor-id=` were suggested [here](https://mathiashueber.com/fighting-error-43-nvidia-gpu-virtual-machine/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/b5xpua/the_ultimate_beginners_guide_to_gpu_passthrough/)
- `+kvm_pv_unhalt` and `+kvm_pv_eoi` were suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/b5xpua/the_ultimate_beginners_guide_to_gpu_passthrough/)
- `topoext` was suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Improving_performance_on_AMD_CPUs)
- `amd-stibp=off` was suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#QEMU_5.0:_host-passthrough_with_kernel_version_5.5_to_5.8.1_when_using_Zen_2_processors:_Windows_10_BSOD_loop_%27KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE%27)
- `hv_relaxed`, `hv-vapic`, `hv-spinlocks`, `hv_vpindex`, `hv-runtime`, `hv_time`, `hv-synic`, `hv-stimer`, `hv-reset`, and `hv-frequencies` were suggested [here](https://youtu.be/L1JCCdo1bG4?t=191), [here](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/gpu-passthrough-issue-vfio-error-000000-0-failed-to-open-dev-vfio-1-no-such-file-or-directory/138572) and [here](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/i386/hyperv.html)
- `x-pci-sub-vendor-id` and `x-pci-sub-device-id` were suggested [here](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/gpu-passthrough-issue-vfio-error-000000-0-failed-to-open-dev-vfio-1-no-such-file-or-directory/138572)
- I also tried `romfile=` in the device extracting the rom with GPU-Z as suggested [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GPU_passthrough_with_libvirt_qemu_kvm#Fixed_Vega_56.2F64_reset_bug), [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#UEFI_(OVMF)_compatibility_in_VBIOS) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/b5xpua/the_ultimate_beginners_guide_to_gpu_passthrough/).

I also have my kernel command appended with `amd_iommu=on iommu=pt pcie_acs_override=downstream,multifunction nofb video=vesafb:off,efifb:off"`. This was suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Enabling_IOMMU), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/b5xpua/the_ultimate_beginners_guide_to_gpu_passthrough/) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Host_unable_to_boot_and_stuck_in_black_screen_after_enabling_vfio).

Before running the VM I run the following script:

```
sysctl vm.nr_hugepages=16384 vm.min_free_kbytes=112640 kernel.shmmax=34359738368

sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/compact_memory

echo 0 > /sys/module/kvm/parameters/report_ignored_msrs
echo 1 > /sys/module/kvm/parameters/ignore_msrs
echo 1 > /sys/module/vfio_iommu_type1/parameters/allow_unsafe_interrupts


systemctl stop lightdm
systemctl isolate multi-user

while systemctl is-active --quiet lightdm; do
    sleep 1
done

echo 0 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind

echo efi-framebuffer.0 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/efi-framebuffer/unbind || :
echo 1 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/efi-framebuffer/unbind || :

echo '0000:2d:00.1' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:2d:00.1/driver/unbind' || :

echo 'vfio-pci' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:2d:00.0/driver_override'
echo 'vfio-pci' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:2d:00.1/driver_override'
echo '1002 ab28' > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id
echo '1002 73bf' > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id
```

- it was suggested mostly [here](https://gitlab.com/risingprismtv/single-gpu-passthrough/-/blob/master/hooks/vfio-startup.sh).
- `vm.nr_hugepages` was suggested [here](https://mathiashueber.com/configuring-hugepages-use-virtual-machine/)
- `drop_caches` and `compact_memory` were suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Dynamic_huge_pages)
- `ignore_msrs` and `report_ignored_msrs` were suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Bluescreen_at_boot_since_Windows_10_1803) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/b5xpua/the_ultimate_beginners_guide_to_gpu_passthrough/).
- `allow_unsafe_interrupts` was suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/b5xpua/the_ultimate_beginners_guide_to_gpu_passthrough/) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1039315/qemu-with-gpu-pass-through-wont-start)

As you can see, I've followed several recommendations, even for those unrelated to code 43, I'm running out of ideas how to solve that...

### PC Specifications

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 Kernel 5.15.0-41-generic
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X
- GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT
- Motherboard: MSI B550 Gaming Carbon WiFi
- QEMU: 4.2.1 (I've also tried with 7.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue with my RX 6900 XT by disabling Resizable BAR in the BIOS.

Comment: This one worked for me on RX6400 (Navi 24). `vfio-pci` module loaded and `GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT="amd_iommu=on iommu=pt"` of course. Not a silver bullet though, as I would like to pass my RTX3060 with bar support.

Answer (score 0):

take a try with bellow grub command

```
amd_iommu=on iommu=pt nofb nomodeset video=vesafb:off,efifb:off vga=normal i915.modeset=0
```

or

```
amd_iommu=on iommu=pt nofb nomodeset video=efifb:off vga=normal i915.modeset=0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).